# jQuery append does not work ( consistently ) on IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, calendar, append, twitter-bootstrap

I've built a stripped down example of what is not working on IE :
http://so.demuyt.net/case1/

( IE8. jQuery 1.7.1 )

Clicking one date in IE does nothing, clicking a second date will put a 'green pill' next to the first and second selected date. Doing this in Chrome will put 1 pill with the first click and 1 pill with the second click.

I add a 'pill' like this:

```
$("#canvas").append('<span class="label label-success Workcounter ' + date + ' ' + calendarName + '">1</span>');
```

I position the 'pill' like this:

```
$(".Workcounter." + date + '.' + calendarName).position( { of : $(".Work-date-highlight."+calendarName+"."+date) , at : "left top" , offset : "3 3" } );
```

There are no errors in js console, what I have noticed is that in debug mode, I will see the pill added in Chrome, whereas I wont see it added in IE (even when I click the second date).

Any help or pointers would be very appreciated to make IE behave like Chrome & FireFox.

Comment: I just tested in IE7, IE8, IE9, and IE10 and it appears to work in each. I clicked a date, and the green pill was added to the top-left of each.

Comment: @JonathanSampson no way.. So the first date you clicked ( just one ) immediately showed a pill without having to click a second date ?

Comment: @JonathanSampson okay, so I checked IE7: works. IE8 only works with 'Compatibility View' for me, was that turned on for you ?

Comment: worked for me in ie6 and 7, problem as described in ie8.

Comment: It's working in IE8 for me, though I am noticing that moving my mouse in and out of certain months causes the pill to flicker, and hide, then show again. Unfortunately I'm not able to troubleshoot right now, but will later if this is not resolved. I would encourage you to fix the validation errors (http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3a%2f%2fso.demuyt.net%2fcase1%2f) and then proceed from there.

Comment: @JonathanSampson the validation errors are gone, but the behaviour remains..

Comment: @tomdemuyt I'm currently looking into this.

Comment: Sure seems like some sort of weird browser bug.  I can find the element with the DOM inspector and it shows the right position, etc.  Unchecking and re-checking a few of the css properties causes it to show up.  very odd.

Comment: I'm curious, if you position the element yourself with `top` and `left` instead of `position`, does it make a difference?

Comment: It looks like the _updateDatepicker hackery is only firing once in IE8. So, pills.length stays at '0'. Every other browser fires it twice and updates the pills value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you use to position the element seems to be causing the problem for me, try replacing:

```
$(".Workcounter." + date + '.' + calendarName).position( { of : $(".Work-date-highlight."+calendarName+"."+date) , at : "left top" , offset : "3 3" } );
```

with:

```
var datePos = $(".Work-date-highlight."+calendarName+"."+date).position();

$(".Workcounter." + date + '.' + calendarName).css({
    left: datePos.left - 3,
    top: datePos.top - 3,
    position: 'absolute'
});
```

Comment: In the actual site, I did have to replace .position() with .offset() because the calendar was in a parent div that was not placed at (0,0). Thanks!